# How to set a default value to a filter in performance point?

Tags: performancepoint

I have a issue while defaulting a value to a filter in performance point.

In the filter right now I have three things: ALL, INVISIBLE ACCOUNTS, VISIBLE ACCOUNT.

when I deploy the dashboard to SharePoint by default it is showing all the values as it is defaulted to "All".

But the customer don't want to see all the accounts. They just want to see the VISIBLE Accounts only. Not sure how to set the default value= VISIBLE Account instead of ALL?

Thanks in Advance,
Shahsra

Answer (score 0):

Need to right click on the value which we need to make it default and it will show the options to default it.